# sum() function in mysql for every 6 rows

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table having time,date, sales field. Time interval is of every half hour. I want to add the sales field for every three hour i.e I want apply sum() function on every six rows on 'sales' field. How to do it?

Comment: Can you post your table structure with some sample data with expected output?

Comment: Post your sql code if you have something. Post your table data and structure.

Comment: @Bikesh P My table structute is like this one: 'code' 2015-01-31                | 00:00:00 | 25778 |
| 2015-01-31                | 00:30:00 | 23304 |
| 2015-01-31                | 01:00:00 | 21318 |
| 2015-01-31                | 01:30:00 | 19024 |
| 2015-01-31                | 02:00:00 | 17022 |
| 2015-01-31                | 02:30:00 | 14733 |
| 2015-01-31                | 03:00:00 | 12593 |
| 2015-01-31                | 03:30:00 | 11048 |
| 2015-01-31                | 04:00:00 |  9364 |
| 2015-01-31                | 04:30:00 |  9364 | I want to add every 3 hour sales i.e every 6 rows